# How to write a line starting and ending with ‘...’ in Python?

Tags: python

Say for example I want to print ‘I can fly’, including the quotations.
How to write the print statement?

Comment: `print("'I can fly'")`

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
print(" 'hi' ")
```

`output: 'hi'`

Comment: Say I want to type ‘this boy’s book’ . I have seen people here using ‘\’ in the print statement. How and where to use ‘\’?

Comment: Anytime you need to [escape a character](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)